# send data through ajax and get it on node js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I would like to send let's say 2 variables to node js server. I know how to do it with one... But if I want to send two datas, which could be separately read in node and then written into xml file the method I used doesnt work.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
if (req.method === "POST") {
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        requestData += data;
        console.log(data.toString());
        fs.appendFile('name.xml','<XML>' +  data + '\n</XML>', function (err) {

    });

});
```

}

That was node js code sample how I get data from ajax call.

```
var info2value = $('#edittocatch').val();
var colorvalue = $('#catchColor').val();
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5073/',
                data:  info2value

            });
```

And now what should I do to send data2 data3 etc?

Comment: data should be sent as key/value pairs

Answer (score 1):

Use an object as the value of the Ajax data property, adding the variables as property values:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5073/',
  data: { info2value: info2value, colorvalue: colorvalue }
});
```

As for NodeJS, you would use [`url`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) and [`querystring`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options) to parse the URL into an object that you can access with the usual dot notation.

```
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var urlObj = url.parse(req.url);
  var qs = querystring.parse(urlObj.query)

  // access the URL parameters with dot notation eg: qs.infoValue2
});
```

`url.parse` will give you something like:

```
{ protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: '127.0.0.1:5073',
  port: '5073',
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  hash: null,
  search: '?info2value=moose&colorvalue=red',
  query: 'info2value=moose&colorvalue=red',
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/?info2value=moose&colorvalue=red',
  href: 'http://127.0.0.1:5073/?info2value=moose&colorvalue=red' }
```

And from there `querystring.parse` on the `query` property of that object will give you:

```
{ info2value: 'moose', colorvalue: 'red' }
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any nodeJS but this will probably do what you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I handled it with   Data.split(" "). It creates array with seperate strings.